# eclipse : Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, eclipse, nullpointerexception, awt

(I am new to java so please don't make your answer TOOOOOOO CONFUSING!!!! :P.)
I just have created a game using eclipse and I really wanted to make a fun game! I looked off of some tutorials that helped me create this. The thing is I can't move in the game. I would really appreciate help!
Here is the error I recieve while trying to move using wasd in my game:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at StickFireBasic.KeyAdapt.keyReleased(KeyAdapt.java:19)
    at java.awt.Component.processKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
My class files are: Main, GameFrame, Entity, Player , KeyAdapt.
```

### Main:

```
package StickFireBasic;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("StickFire");
        frame.setSize(800, 600);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setResizable(true);
        frame.add(new GameFrame());
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

### GameFrame:

```
package StickFireBasic;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class GameFrame  extends JPanel implements ActionListener{
    
    Timer mainTimer;
    Player player;
    
    public GameFrame() {
        setFocusable(true);
        
        player = new Player(400, 300);
        addKeyListener(new KeyAdapt(player));
        mainTimer = new Timer(10, this);
        mainTimer.start();
    }
    
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        player.draw(g2d);

    }
    
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        player.update();
        repaint();
    }
}
```

### Entity:

```
package StickFireBasic;

import java.awt.Graphics2D;

public class Entity {
    
    int x, y;
    
    public Entity(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    
    public void update() {
        
    }

    public void draw(Graphics2D g2d) {
        
    }
}
```

### Player:

```
package StickFireBasic;

import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class Player extends Entity{
    
    int velX = 0, velY = 0;

    public Player(int x, int y) {
        super(x, y);
        
    }
    
    public void update() {
        y += velY;
        x += velX;
    }
    
    public void draw(Graphics2D g2d) {
        g2d.drawImage(getPlayerImg(), x, y, null);
    }
    
    public Image getPlayerImg() {
        
        
        ImageIcon ic = new ImageIcon("C:/img/stickguy.png/");
        return ic.getImage();
    }
    
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        int key = e.getKeyCode();
        
        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_W) {
            velY = -2;
        } else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_S) {
            velY = 2;
        } else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_A) {
            velX = -2;
        } else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_D) {
            velX = 2;
        }
        
    }
    
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        int key = e.getKeyCode();
        
        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_W) {
            velY = 0;
        } else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_S) {
            velY = 0;
        } else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_A) {
            velX = 0;
        } else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_D) {
            velX = 0;
        }
        
    }

}
```

### KeyAdapt:

```
package StickFireBasic;

import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class KeyAdapt  extends KeyAdapter {
    
    Player p;
    
    public KeyAdapt(Player player) {
        
    }
    
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        p.keyPressed(e);
    }
    
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        p.keyReleased(e);
    }

}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Well, this looks wrong to me:

```
Player p;

public KeyAdapt(Player player) {

}
```

Shouldn't you be assigning a value to `p` somewhere? Like the constructor? Currently you're completely ignoring the constructor parameter.

Otherwise, it will always have a null value - so when you dereference it in your handlers, it will throw a `NullPointerException`. You should also rename it to be more descriptive, quite possibly rename the class itself, and make it private and final:

```
public class PlayerKeyAdapter extends KeyAdapter {
    private final Player player;

    public PlayerKeyAdapter(Player player) {
        this.player = player;
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        player.keyPressed(e);
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        player.keyReleased(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: now I have a bunch of errors by the numbers in eclipse next to player. and private final player;

Comment: @user1546217: Doh, typo - fixed, but you should try to work out what was wrong yourself. Read the error message carefully.

Comment: still have an error under PlayerKeyAdapter saying The blank field might not have been initalized and also the return type for KeyAdapt(Player [player isn't returned

Comment: i am trying but sorry I am new to java

Comment: hey I fixed it! sorry 'bout the trouble

Comment: @user1546217: Okay, I'm sorry about the typos too - I'm doing too many things at once - but it's worth making sure you really understand the Java language before you do too much more. Personally I'd recommend writing *console* applications before you start on GUIs; that way there's a lot less to go wrong, and fewer odd rules to follow etc. It lets you learn the language and core libraries from scratch, without as many distractions.

Comment: is there anyway i can learn java esaliy without youtube videos?

Comment: @user1546217: Absolutely - read books, write code, start from scratch and work up instead of trying to start with GUIs.